# Accessing object members inside a vector, inside another object, out of range

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, stl

I am new to C++, and I am making a menu system for the output console, simply using cin and cout. I have made a structure like so:

The UI Object has a vector of MENU objects, which in turn each have a vector of Item objects. Each Item is essentially a menu item, that can be selected. I then want to use my UI Object to call a menu page (showMenu()), which then prints the items for that menu.

Here's my problem: When I call my UI function, that prints a menu, then the items act all weird. My program crashes, and complains about my vector being out of range?
When I use the Menu print(draw()) function, by it self, then it works, but when I do it through my UI class, it crashes.

Here is a simplified version of my code, there are destructors, setters and getters, I just left them out here:

```
class ui
{
public:
    ui();
    void addMenu(menu&);
    void showMenu(size_t menuNumber);
private:
    vector<menu> menus_;
    vector<menu>::iterator menuIt;
};
class menu
{
public:
    menu();
    menu(string name);
    string getMenuName();
    void makeItem(string name, size_t link, size_t up, size_t down, size_t right, size_t left, COORD position, int type);
    void draw();
private:
    vector<item> items_;
    vector<item>::iterator itemIt;
    string name_;
};
class item
{
public:
    item();
    item(string name, size_t link, size_t up, size_t down, size_t right, size_t left, COORD position, int type);
private:
    size_t      up_;
    size_t      down_;
    size_t      right_;
    size_t      left_;
    COORD       position_;
    size_t      link_;
    int         type_;
    string      name_;
};
void ui::showMenu(size_t menuNumber)
{
    this->menus_.at(menuNumber).draw();
}
void ui::addMenu(menu& menu)
{
    menus_.push_back(menu);
}
menu::menu(string name)
{
    name_ = name;
}
void menu::makeItem(std::string name, size_t link, size_t up, size_t down, size_t right, size_t left, COORD position, int type)
{
    item* newItem = new item(name, link, up, down, right, left, position, type);
    items_.push_back(*newItem);
}
void menu::draw()
{
    cout << name_ << endl; // THIS WORKS!

    // Print menu items: <- THIS DOES NOT WORK!
    for (itemIt = items_.begin(); itemIt!=items_.end(); itemIt++)
    {
        // Do Stuff to menu items!
    }
}
item::item(std::string name, size_t link, size_t up, size_t down, size_t right, size_t left, COORD position, int type)
{
    name_ = name;
    up_ = up;
    down_ = down;
    right_ = right;
    left_ = left;
    position_ = position;
    link_ = link;
    type_ = type;
}
```

In my main, I have made a UI object, then proceeded to use the to make menus and items. I then call the following:

```
Main:
#include "ui.h"
#include "item.h"
#include "menu.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    ui ui;

    // Menus:
    menu menu1("Main menu");
    ui.addMenu(menu1);
                                             // L, u, d, r, l, pos,      type
    menu1.makeItem("Add device",                2, 0, 1, 0, 0, { 4,11 }, 0);
    menu1.makeItem("All devices",               3, 0, 2, 0, 0, { 4,12 }, 0);
    menu1.makeItem("Activity",                  4, 1, 3, 0, 0, { 4,13 }, 0);
    menu1.makeItem("Exit",                      5, 2, 3, 0, 0, { 4,14 }, 0);

    menu1.draw(); // Which works!
    ui.showMenu(0); // Which crashes!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to include a [mre], which includes the `main` with the calls to `makeMenu` and `makeItem`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint 1201ProgramAlarm. Just edited it ;-)

Comment: The `ui.addMenu` call will create a copy of `menu1`. You add items to `menu1`, but the copy stored in `ui` does not have any items added to it.

Comment: Thank you! Makes total sense, I just add items to menu, before adding menu to UI, and now it works!